Mi componente desaparece cuando llamo la funcion getHTML() en tiptap
Estoy utilizando TipTap como editor de mi blog, estoy intentando insertar un tweet en mi editor, para estoy estoy utilizando la opción que tiene twitter, para que me pueda renderizar el tweet cree una extensión propia:
import { Node } from '@tiptap/core';

const MyCustomNode = Node.create({
  name: 'tweetComponent',

  group: 'block',

  // Aquí defines el HTML que va a estar disponible para tu nodo
  renderHTML() {
    return ['div', { class: 'my-custom-node' }, 0]
  },

  parseHTML() {
    return [
      {
        tag: 'div',
      },
    ]
  },

  // Opcionalmente puedes definir cómo debe verse cuando se edita
  addNodeView() {
    return ({ node, view, getPos }) => {
      const dom = document.createElement('div');
      dom.innerHTML = node.attrs.content;

      // Cargar el script de Twitter para inicializar el widget
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.twttr) {
        window.twttr.widgets.load(dom);
      }

      return { dom };
    };
  },
});

Al insertarlo todo va bien, pero el problema es cuando en el editor llamo la función getHTML() desaparece el componente, lo que si pude notar al revisarlo el html, aparece de la siguiente forma
<div class="my-custom-node"></div>

Según revise, podría ser un problema de parseHTML() o renderHTML(), pero no se como deberia de cargar este elemento o como seria apropiado colocarlo en estas funciones.
